# Twitter API search within following 

Tags: api, search, twitter

wondering if anyone has heard of a way to filter Twitter search results to the users 'following' list? I'd like to do a search for pics that people I follow have posted. The pics part is fairly trivial (search for image URLs) but I'm guessing that a user-filtered search is beyond the API, even with oAuth.

I've seen a couple of services like snapbird.org that advertise this feature (even though they don't seem to work well), any guesses as to how they go about this?

Thanks!

Comment: How does this relate to programming / software development?

Comment: I was under the impression that you just wanted to find a web-site that offered that functionality. It would help if you would clarify in your question body and/or title that you are using the official Twitter API. Also, add the "Twitter-API" tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this specific image search easily with the help of jetwick.com available as open source here: https://github.com/karussell/Jetwick

Currently searching in your friends is possible but adding yet another filter isn't that hard. Patches are welcome ;)

Comment: Wow great project and nice that you open-sourced it. So this type of search is non-trivial.

Comment: It is non-trivial if you want to offer it to a lot users. Doing this only for your personal usage is very easy: just put your tweets into a big array list. Java should be fast enough that you don't need to use Lucene or ElasticSearch :)

Comment: Thanks again, I've not done much Java beyond playing with Google Appspot + Processing. I was hoping there would be some way of doing this via the API but I realize now it's not possible (updated question to reflect this). Twitter should partner with Google to run their search API :-)